# Show that $\left|z+z\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}} \right| > 1$, for all $|z| < 1$ where $\mathrm{Im}(z) \ne 0$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I am having difficulty showing that

$$\left|z+z\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}} \right| > 1$$

for all $|z| < 1$ where $\mathrm{Im}(z) \ne 0$. Here, the square root is defined as
$$z = re^{i\theta} \text{ where } r > 0, \theta \in (-\pi, \pi] \text{ and } \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{r}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}.$$
I tried by writing $z = x+yi$ but I wasn't able to get much.
I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

Let $w_{1,2}=  z\pm z\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}$ and note that

$$w^2-2zw+1=0$$

Then, $|w_1||w_2|=1$. The discriminant is of complex if $\mathrm{Im}(z) \ne 0$, ensuring $|w_1|\ne|w_2|$.